# Merge Rich Text?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, richtext

I have an application which involves building rich text character by character in order to undo it all at once. In order to retain that character's formatting, I select it and then can add the SelectedRtf property to my StringBuilder, however I want to be able to build each Rich Text character into one Rich Text string so that I can undo it in one go.

My question is how can you combine Rich Text strings into one big string while retaining all the formatting for each character.

Comment: pls can you elaborate "undo it in one go" part

Comment: In most professional programs (Word, Notepad++, VS etc.) If you press delete 5 times, you only have to press undo once to undo it all. Hence each time you press delete, I want to add the deleted character to a StringBuilder so that pressing undo will put it all back again with only one button press.

Answer (score 1):

merge it this way:

```
richTextBox2.Select(richTextBox2.TextLength, 0);
richTextBox2.SelectedRtf = richTextBox1.Rtf;
```