# Numbers And Special Characters Don't Work In Replace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to replace `a` to `4` in a RichTextBox. It replaces the text "a" not with "4" but with "4nsi4nsicpg1252ng16393rd4r"..

This is the code i'm using:
`RichTextBox1.Rtf = RichTextBox1.Rtf.Replace("a", "4")`

Any help on how I can replace an "a" with a "4"? BTW I can replace "a" with "test" but not "4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (Rich Text Format) is a mix of the text of your document and control words that describe how to format the text.  The `RichTextBox1.Rtf` property returns RTF, not plain text, so your `Replace` statement is corrupting some of those RTF control words.  For example, your RTF probably starts:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252 ...
```

Where `\rtf1`, `\ansi` and `\ansicpg1252` are RTF control words.  Your `Replace` changed that to:

```
{\rtf1\4nsi\4nsicpg1252 ...
```

Since `\4nsi` and `\4nsicpg1252` are no longer valid RTF control words, they end up being displayed as text - minus the `\` character that is used to indicate the start of a control word.

The [`RichTextBox.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property will return the plain text, so you could try using that instead, but I suspect that this would also strip out any formatting that had been applied to the document:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("a", "4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Find/Replace can be performed in the richtextbox control to preserve the formatting.

```
Private Sub Replace(ByVal findText As String, ByVal replacement As String)
    Dim startIndex = 0
    Dim foundIndex = RichTextBox1.Find(findText, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

    While foundIndex >= 0
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = replacement
        startIndex = foundIndex + replacement.Length
        foundIndex = RichTextBox1.Find(findText, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    End While
End Sub
```

Multiple changes can be combined into a single undo block, using a second richtextbox as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097179